# Is it possible to paste from clipboard onclick in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The use case is for data entry on a private intranet: Users copy and paste from google docs, dropbox text documents etc and have to paste into a form with many inputs. to speed it up for them, it would be nice if the user could copy and paste from the document, and when they click on the input field, it automatically pastes when they left click.

I've seen some older questions, but it appears that this is (and for good reason) a security risk. however, all the users on the private intranet are aware of this and simply want to save time. is there any browser or technique that would allow this?

also, we can use any browser or environment that supports it. How can I then achieve this functionality to save time?

Comment: You might be able to use the new [clipboard api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API).

Comment: [document.execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) paste on contenteditable (or form) elements?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The clipboard API is included in Chrome 66. Check the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/zm490d6a/

Relevant code is:

```
async function paste(input) {
  const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  input.value = text;
}
```

If you are in Chrome 66 or later this will work. However, note that you must give the webpage permission to access the clipboard for security reasons, so the first time you click on the input on that page it will popup asking your permission to access the clipboard. Once you give it access any clicks into the input will paste whatever is on your clipboard.

Here I simply use readText, but you can also use readData for images etc on the clipboard. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
el.addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
    document.execCommand('paste');
});
```

Comment: As of 2023, the use of execCommand is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand