# Get Text from Clipboard with Javascript

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I want to paste Text into a text area on button click. But I have no idea how to get the text from Clipboard. I want to use codemirror and use the function:

```
function insertTextAtCursor(editor, text) {
    var doc = editor.getDoc();
    var cursor = doc.getCursor();
    doc.replaceRange(text, cursor);
}
```

to paste the Text on Button click. Can anybody give me a hint how to get the Text from clipboard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to paste from clipboard onclick in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633601/is-it-possible-to-paste-from-clipboard-onclick-in-javascript)

Comment: check out my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/ZEzWjyg), includes copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigator.clipboard.readText()` with browsers that support it.

```js
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.querySelector('textarea'), {
  lineNumbers: true
});

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (window.navigator) {
    navigator.clipboard.readText().then(setCMText);
  }
});

function setCMText(text) {
  if (editor.getSelection().length) {
    editor.replaceSelection(text);
  } else {
    var doc = editor.getDoc();
    var cursor = doc.getCursor();
    var pos = {
      line: cursor.line,
      ch: cursor.ch
    }
    doc.replaceRange(text, pos);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/codemirror@5.51.0/theme/ambiance.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/codemirror@5.51.0/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/codemirror@5.51.0/lib/codemirror.min.js"></script>

<button>Paste</button>
<textarea>
Hello World
</textarea>
```